# Table manipulation in Kusto?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I am new to the Kusto DB and wondering how we can export the table with specific columns selected from that table to the Azure SQL DB.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can export from Kusto ([Application Insights](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/03/28/introducing-application-analytics/)) to a JSON format file on an Azure storage account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry

Then you can import from the storage account into SQL Azure database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/import-json-documents-into-sql-server#import-json-documents-from-azure-blob-storage

Hope this helps.